# Unrecognized --schema argument sqoop job

Tags: powershell, azure, sqoop, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to run the following sqoop job from Powershell but I end up with an error, saying that --schema is an unrecognized argument:

```
$sqoopDef = New-AzureRmHDInsightSqoopJobDefinition -Command "import --connect $connectionString --target-dir $targetDir --fields-terminated-by \t --lines-terminated-by \n -m $numMappers --table $tableName-- --schema $schema"
```

If I try to run the same job from the command line it works without any error. Is the --schema argument not suported from powershell?

Note: I am using a Spark 1.6.1 Linux cluster on Azure HdInsight. Sqoop version is: 1.4.6.2.4.2.0-258

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to implement a workaround for this issue by using the --options-file argument in the sqoop command. I've removed the --schema argument from the initial command, and pasted it in the options file.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell just passes the command to your HDInsight cluster. If the cluster supports `--schema` when you run a Sqoop job directly on the cluster, then it should also work when submitted via PowerShell.

The issue may be that you have an extra "`--`" appended to the end of your table name.  Try removing that and see if that fixes things.

Comment: I also suspected that the command is passed to the cluster and thus, it shouldn't make any difference from where it's called (cmd or powershell). Anyway, I've already tried a couple of different solutions including removing the "--" you mentioned, but it didn't work.